# How to find summation of the series $1 + \frac {1}{3} + \frac {1\cdot 3}{3\cdot 6} +\cdots$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

How to find summation of the series $1 + \dfrac {1}{3} + \dfrac {1\cdot 3}{3\cdot 6} + \dfrac {1\cdot 3\cdot 5}{3\cdot 6\cdot 9} + \dfrac {1\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot 7}{3\cdot 6\cdot 9\cdot 12} + .....$ ?

I can't find any particular sequence.Please help!

Comment: Are you asking for a numerical value of the summation or for an argument that the series actually converges?

Comment: The numbers for may be expressed as a double factorial, the denominator may be expressed using $3^n$ and $n!$ just factor $3^n$ and see what happens.

Comment: @TedShifrin A sum of n terms if possible!

Comment: You'll never get that, @ZOZ.

Comment: @TedShifrin Sum of infinite terms?

Comment: I was trying to apply binomial theorem for any index..Is that a good idea? @TedShifrin P.S Still trying

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**  For $x\in\mathbb{C}$ with $|x|<\frac12$, $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\,\frac{1}{2^n}\binom{2n}{n}\,x^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\,\binom{-1/2}{n}\,(-2x)^n=(1-2x)^{-1/2}\,.$$

Comment: This seems similar to binomial theorem for any index!

Comment: Well, it is exactly the Binomial Theorem for index $-\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Ok tell me the secret..how did you guess it ? :-P Intuition?

Comment: Well, I recognize that $\binom{2n}{n}=(-1)^n\,2^{2n}\,\binom{-1/2}{n}$ due to experience.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{eqnarray*}1+\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{(2k-1)!!}{k! 3^k}=1+\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{(2k)!}{k!^2 6^k}&=&1+\sum_{k\geq 1}\binom{2k}{k}\frac{1}{6^k}\\&=&\sum_{k\geq 0}\binom{2k}{k}\frac{1}{6^k}\\&=&\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{4}{6}}}=\color{red}{\sqrt{3}}\end{eqnarray*}$$
since the generating function for central binomial coefficients is directly related with [the generating function of Catalan numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number#First_proof).

Answer (score 1):

Using Binomial expansion of  $$(1-x)^{-n} = 1+nx+\frac{n(n+1)}{2}x^2+\frac{n(n+1)(n+2)}{6}x^3+.......$$

So we get $$nx=\frac{1}{3}$$ and $$\frac{nx(nx+x)}{2}=\frac{1}{3}\cdot \frac{3}{6}$$

We get $$\frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{1}{3}+x\right)=\frac{1}{3}\Rightarrow x=\frac{2}{3}$$

So we get $$n=\frac{1}{2}$$

So our series sum is $$(1-x)^{-n} = \left(1-\frac{2}{3}\right)^{-\frac{1}{2}} = \sqrt{3}$$